# Mysql InnoDB and quickly applying large updates

Tags: mysql, ruby, database, innodb

Basically my problem is that I have a large table of about 17,000,000 products that I need to apply a bunch of updates to really quickly.

The table has 30 columns with the id set as int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT.

I have another table which all of the updates for this table are stored in, these updates have to be pre-calculated as they take a couple of days to calculate. This table is in the format of [ product_id int(10), update_value int(10) ].

The strategy I'm taking to issue these 17 million updates quickly is to load all of these updates into memory in a ruby script and group them in a hash of arrays so that each update_value is a key and each array is a list of sorted product_id's.

```
{ 
   150: => [1,2,3,4,5,6],
   160: => [7,8,9,10]
}
```

Updates are then issued in the format of

```
UPDATE product SET update_value = 150 WHERE product_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6);
UPDATE product SET update_value = 160 WHERE product_id IN (7,8,9,10);
```

I'm pretty sure I'm doing this correctly in the sense that issuing the updates on sorted batches of product_id's should be the optimal way to do it with mysql / innodb.

I'm hitting a weird issue though where when I was testing with updating ~13 million records, this only took around 45 minutes. Now I'm testing with more data, ~17 million records and the updates are taking closer to 120 minutes. I would have expected some sort of speed decrease here but not to the degree that I'm seeing.

Any advice on how I can speed this up or what could be slowing me down with this larger record set?

As far as server specs go they're pretty good, heaps of memory / cpu, the whole DB should fit into memory with plenty of room to grow.

Comment: Have you tuned your innodb_* settings so it'll take advantage of your "Heaps of Memory"?

Comment: Yeah the server guys have that one tuned fairly well.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using mysql's multi-table update syntax

```
update product, sometable SET product.update_value=sometable.value WHERE product_id=sometable.whatever;
```

that way it's a single pass through the database and a single big query that mysql can grind through

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to carefully design indexes and data pages access.

Assuming `product_id`s' distribution on a query is random, each of the update SQL will cause random index page accesses.  Of course, data page accesses following the index page accesses are random too.  If you want ALL updates run quickly, you need to have all index pages in memory (at very least).Thus, this is not a fast set of update operation.

If I'm designing it and updates not required to be transactional,
I'll update all of rows, one by one, per product_ids like this not in a transaction:

```
UPDATE product SET update_value = 150 WHERE product_id = 1
UPDATE product SET update_value = 150 WHERE product_id = 2
...
```

Since it will cause both index pages and data pages read/updated sequentially, this scheme possibly take longer update but lot cheaper in cache management point of view. Of course,
the overall impact to the database is minimum, so operations other than update (like query from customer) do not degrade.

If transactional operation is a requirement, I probably want to have two tables, or use some trick to have two logical tables into one table which is cheaper in above cache discussion point of view. But if you don't need to be transactional, slow update per `product_id` is the way to go.